# How to minimize optionals

Tags: swift3, chaining

I want to input a number as a string and am using readLine which returns a String?. Then I want to convert that inputed String to an Int which also returns an Int?. If either optional returns a nil, then print an error; otherwise, use the Int. The following code works but there has to be a better way. Any ideas?

```
print ("Enter number: ", terminator:"")
let number = readLine ()

if number != nil && Int (number!) != nil
{
    let anInt = Int (number!)!
}
else
{
    print ("Input Error")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine the unwrapping of `readLine` response and the conversion to `Int` and making sure the numeric conversion succeeded into a single `guard` statement, e.g.,

```
guard let string = readLine(), let number = Int(string) else {
    print("input error")
    return
}

// use `number`, which is an `Int`, here
```

---

You can obviously spin that around if you want:

```
if let string = readLine(), let number = Int(string) {
    // use `number`, which is an `Int`, here
} else {
    print("input error")
}
```

Comment: Another approach: `guard let number = readLine().map{ Int($0) } else {...`